# How can I connect ESP-WROOM-32 to CM3 without the need for a UART-USB Convertor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, wifi, esp8266

Trying to add the use of the ESP-WROOM-32 and its Wi-fi / bluetooth to my project using eagle however alot of components out there require the use of USB and UART to USB Converters like the CP2102.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to connect up the ESP-WROOM-32 directly into the CM3 without the need for adding additional USB connectors / converters.

I spoke to buddy of mine and he suggested this page could be of some use: https://oshlab.com/esp8266-raspberry-pi-gpio-wifi/

Would this work the same for my project? or would I have to adapt the design to work differently.

I'm a newbie to electronics so what may come easy to you may require a bit of in-depth explaining so I can get my head around it. Cheers.

Comment: What is this CM3 of which you speak?!

Comment: This is unanswerable without the identification of the other system.  Generally though you'd connect it via interconnecting serial UARTs, or perhaps SPI or I2C engines - additionally schemes are possible, but those are the most common.  You should also consider if you can do your entire project on the ESP32 without needing the other system at all.

Comment: @DiBosco CM3 is Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3